# Use of (STL) copy with undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, stl

In an assessment I chose the option *runtime error on LINE I*.
There was no such option as *Undefined Behaviour* although I thought that would be the correct option to choose.

I am not sure but I'd reckon there is a mistake in the assessment. I compiled and ran the program and it prints indeed `3, 9, 0, 2, 1, 4, 5,` with three different compilers ([Cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/42rq2), [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aTnEtXdOVomhuIj1) and locally on Mac OS X).

**Does the program have Undefined Behaviour due to LINE I?**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void printer(int i) {
        cout << i << ", ";
}
int main() {
        int mynumbers[] = { 3, 9, 0, 2, 1, 4, 5 };
        vector<int> v1(mynumbers, mynumbers + 7);
        copy(mynumbers, mynumbers + 7, v1.end());//LINE I
        for_each(v1.begin(), v1.end(), printer);//LINE II
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's UB.

The first thing `std::copy` will do is dereference `v1.end()`, and doing so [causes undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end).

Comment: Can *undefined behavior* be considered a particular case of *run-time error*? If so, the text of the assignment was correct, wasn't it?

Comment: @ElProfesor I wouldn't call it a runtime error. UB can give you any effect, including no error at all (which is what happened to OP). And since UB in OP's code happens unconditionally, I believe it [could](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.undefined) even cause a compile-time error.

Comment: Thanks. So, do you think the wording should be then *it is undefined behavior, and therefore it may result in a run-time error*? Better like this?

Comment: @ElProfesor Looks better to me.